# Modifying White Space Elements From Element in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following array of arrays:

```
arr1= ["avd befe, bla, bla, bla, bla", "cveve devev, bla, bla, bla, bla", "aava beve. cavbr, bla, bla, bla, bla", "feve gyhyh, bla, bla, bla, bla", "ibtbt, bla, bla, bla, bla"]
```

In my example, I am focused on the first group of characters in the array. These can include items that are of the format "x", "x y" (w a blank space between two groups of characters), and "x y z" (w two blank spaces between three groups of characters.

I would like to delete the y from the third group of elements (so that "x y z" becomes "x z"). arr1 shown above is an example - the array I'm working with has a couple hundred entries. In that example above, I'd want "aava beve. cavbr" to become "aava cavbr" in the third element in arr1.

Comment: you want to remove the white space , just like "a b" -->"ab" right?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to search through all of the first elements for the inner arrays and do the following "x y z" -->"x z".

Comment: The first elements in the inner arrays are in one of three forms: "x", "x y", and "x y z"...I only want to find the ones that are of the form "x y z" and remove the inner character

Comment: you mean only find the first element in array and remove the "x y z" -->"x y",What the rule of the character you want to remove?

Comment: Right - so the first elements can be either 1) "x" 2) "x y" 3) "x y z". I only want to modify #3

Comment: for example : "a b. c" -->"a b"  you want to format like "character"+"white space"+"character"   right?

Comment: Yes - but I want "a b. c" --> "a c"

Comment: the "first character" + "white space" + "last character" right?
like this :"x ys fs.f z" --> "x z"?

Comment: Well it is the first group of characters + whitespace + last group of characters...like "xsfs dfdfd lsjfldsfkjs" --> "xsfs lsjfldsfkjs"

Comment: you wanna whole element of array or the element's first element of array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making assumptions, based on your question, that these will *always and only* be in the first place in the nested arrays.

```
// loop over the inner arrays
arr1.forEach(function(innerArr) {
  var parts = innerArr[0].split(' ');
  innerArr[0] = parts[0] + ' ' + parts[ parts.length - 1 ];
});
```

If those elements never have additional spaces in them (e.g. it's always "x y z" and not "x y some other stuff with spaces in it z" then you can just do `innerArr[0].replace(/\s[^ ]\s/, '');` but I wasn't clear on the exact form of your data.

EDIT:

Based on the new data format, here's more what you're after.

```
var newArr = arr1.map(function(val) {
  var parts = val.split(',');
  var words = parts[0].split(' ');
  if (words.length > 2) {
    parts[0] = words[0] + ' ' + words[ words.length - 1 ];
  }
  return parts.join(',');
});
```

Comment: I'll take a look - but for my purposes this assumption of it always and only being in the first place is valid and sufficient

Comment: It's because I'm a doofus. I mixed my regex with strings. Try EITHER `.split(' ')` or `.split(/\s/)` . . . but not both like I just did. I'll update the answer.

Comment: No worries - I appreciate the effort; I posted bc I was stumped myself, so no harm in trying

Comment: Should work now. I also removed the totally inaccurate code comment that was residual from a previous thought that I erased. Well, actually, it's the `innerArr[0].replace(/\s[^ ]\s/, '');` thing. That actually should work by the way and is only one line, as opposed to two or more (like all the other answers).

Comment: I apologize - you know what I made an error in stating the problem

Comment: I'm really sorry - it is not an array of arrays, it is an array where each element is a long string of characters separated by commas. I want to remove the whitespace from the first group of characters (i.e. before the first comma) to make "ksdjflsj sldfkjsl lsjflsjd, ..." --> "ksdjflsj lsjflsjd"

Comment: Oh . . . ok. Give me a sec.

Comment: The first solution - I thought it worked but it has an adverse consequence of modifying elements that are not of the "kfjkdj dkjfdkjf dkfjdkjfdk" format. It repeats the first group of characters so something like "kfjd dkjfdk" becomes "kfjd kfjd dkjfdk". The second simpler solution didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you question correctly , maybe code like this :

```
arr1.map(function(ele){
    var current = ele[0].split(' ');
    var head = current.shift();      // head is first group
    var tail = current.pop();        // tail is last  group
    // console.log(head.concat([' '],tail));
    return head.concat([' '],tail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to get the first and last values and keep them separated by a whitespace character. Here's the easiest way I can think to do that:

```
var arr1 = ["avd befe, bla, bla, bla, bla", "cveve devev, bla, bla, bla, bla", "aava beve. cavbr, bla, bla, bla, bla", "feve gyhyh, bla, bla, bla, bla", "ibtbt, bla, bla, bla, bla"]

function clean(str) {
  var foo = str.split(",")[0];
  var bar = foo.substr(0, foo.indexOf(" ")) + foo.substr(foo.lastIndexOf(" "));
  return str.replace(foo, bar);
}
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = clean(arr1[i]);
}
```

Comment: The way you phrased the problem is correct. I will take a look at your solution

Comment: After reading some of the other answers, I realize you might also be asking for a way to iterate over the nested arrays. Should I edit my answer with help for that as well?

Comment: Hi - I rephrased the entire question. I made an error in the problem statement. There is no nested arrays - It is an array where each element is a long string of characters with blocks separated by commas. Focusing on the first group of characters, I want to remove the middle group of characters that is before the first comma

Comment: I updated it to work with strings separated by commas. Does this work?